# Should I be storing this information as the attribute of an entity and then retrieve it? Or simply query it with instances of association?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

Structure of database for the problem:

```
tv_shows
    tv_show_id, 
    tv_show_title, 
    tv_show_description, 
    network, 
    status

episodes
    episode_id, 
    tv_show_id, 
    episode_title, 
    episode_description, 
    air_date
```

Hi,

I am unsure of what’s best here. To output the number of episodes of tv_show1, should I make this an attribute of the tv_shows table and include it? (i.e. “”no_of_episodes”) Or simply count the number of episodes where there’s an occurrence of the id for tv_show1 in the episodes table with a query?

That’s not all...Something else is riddling me with this task. If I wanted the premiere date of tv_show1, would I also make this an attribute in the tv_shows table? Or retrieve it by simply querying the earliest instance of an episode’s air_date?

Both solutions work but I have no idea what's correct

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of thumb in database design: *only store each piece of information in one place.*

While your system might run slightly faster if you store each count, you will also have to adjust those counts each time you add or remove an episode.  Consequently, it's better just to count the records each time you query.